# I can't add derived classes on Oracle db thaut add-migration and update-database using ASP.NET Core (code first)

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to create database for my project app.

I have those 3 classes:

Base class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace project.Core.Models;

public class Ordreintervention
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Typeordre { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dated { get; set; }
}
```

Derived classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace project.Core.Models;

public class Ordreinterventionexterne : Ordreintervention
{
    public int? Codefournisseur { get; set; }

    public virtual Fournisseur? CodefournisseurNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace project.Core.Models;

public class Ordreinterventioninterne : Ordreintervention
{
    public int? Codedepartementdmet { get; set; }

    public virtual Departementdmet? CodedepartementdmetNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

After I run:

```
add-migration test
update-database
```

I got only the `Ordreintervention` table created in the Oracle database.

How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 0):

It is an expected behavior in EF Core for derived classes. It is due to some performance issues and is set default after EF Core 5. To create all data tables , you need to configure in your dbcontext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Ordreintervention>()
        .ToTable("Ordreinterventions");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Ordreinterventionexterne>()
        .ToTable("Ordreinterventionexternes");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Ordreinterventioninterne>()
        .ToTable("Ordreinterventioninternes");
}
```